# How to use environment variables in _config.yml?

Tags: build, jekyll

I am a complete newbie to jekyll (and don't know ruby). But I was able to build https://angry-tereshkova-959566.netlify.com and publish at netlify in two days, so I am a fan. (This site will soon go live).

I want to use Netlify build previews, but they have an unpredictable url. So I want to access environment variable DEPLOY_PRIME_URL in my _config.yml.

I've searched, and found many people asking this question, but no answers. I tried jekyll-environment-variables, but it produces a Dependency Error which I have not figured out how to resolve.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more information about the error, all I can do is tell you how I use variables in Jekyll.

Add the following to `config.rb`

```rb
set :VARNAME, 'http://your-deploy-prime-url.com'
config[:VARNAME]
```

Then, to recall it I use:

```
<%= config[:VARNAME] %>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. There's no config.rb file in my repo (it's a template

But I was able to use an env var in this way:

```
printf "site: %s" "$DEPLOY_URL" > _config_netlify.yml; jekyll build --config _config.yml,_config_netlify.yml
```